# how to change this function ( disp_str ) to 64-bit version

Tags: assembly, operating-system, nasm

This is the whole file and the `disp_str` would be used in *.c file

And I'm new to github.

If I got a 64-bit version of this file ,I could learn from it.

```
[SECTION .data]
disp_pos    dd  0

[SECTION .text]

global  disp_str

; ========================================================================
;                  void disp_str(char * info);
; ========================================================================
disp_str:
    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov esi, [ebp + 8]  ; pszInfo
    mov edi, [disp_pos]
    mov ah, 0Fh
.1:
    lodsb
    test    al, al
    jz  .2
    cmp al, 0Ah 
    jnz .3
    push    eax
    mov eax, edi
    mov bl, 160
    div bl
    and eax, 0FFh
    inc eax
    mov bl, 160
    mul bl
    mov edi, eax
    pop eax
    jmp .1
.3:
    mov [gs:edi], ax
    add edi, 2
    jmp .1

.2:
    mov [disp_pos], edi

    pop ebp
    ret
```

Because my computer is 64-bit ,so I need to convert it to 64-format.

This code is found by me in a book.**I guess this code is to print a string in screen,is it right?**

Comment: I suggest you simply convert the function back to C and then compile it with a 64-bit compiler.

Comment: You know , this code is found by me in a book. I don't know what do you mean by "convert back to C" ?

Answer (score 1):

The code appears to be writing text to an 80-column PC text-mode style buffer,
where every cell is described by a byte containing colour information (four bit
foreground, one bit blink, three bit background) and a byte for the character,
setting everything to white on black, or black on white.

However, it doesn't handle scrolling, it doesn't handle lines longer than 80
characters, and it doesn't update the hardware cursor.

It uses a `gs:` segment override to write to the output, which suggests it's
probably going directly to video memory; but I don't see that descriptor being
set up in that code, so I don't know what value it should have.  This might be
standard on your OS, or DOS extender, or whatever you have.

I don't think you need to convert it to 64-bit, as your computer should support
running 32-bit code anyway.

However, if you do need to do that for some reason, you can try compiling this
C code which I think is roughly equivalent.

```
extern short *disp_ptr;
void disp_str(char *s)
{
    int c;
    /* fetch the current write position */
    short *p = disp_pos;

    /* read characters from the string passed to the function, and stop
     * when we reach a 0.
     */
    while ((c = *s++) != '\0')
    {
        /* If we see a newline in the string:
         */
        if (c == '\n')
        {
            intptr_t i = (intptr_t)p;

            /* round the address down to a multiple of 160 (80 16-bit
             * values), and add one to advance the write pointer to the
             * start of the next line.
             */
            i /= 160;
            i = (i & 255) + 1;
            i *= 160;
            p = (void *)i;
        }
        else
        {
            /* write the character to the screen along with colour
             * information
             */
            *p++ = c | 0x0f00;
        }
    }

    /* write the modified pointer back out to static storage. */
    disp_pos = p;
}
```

Comment: Thank you . I was suppose to guess that github may have one.

Comment: @guotong1988, what is the book?  It might be easier to point to an appropriate source if we know the book title.

Comment: It is a Chinese book called <<OS From Scratch>>

Comment: I prepare to change this code by changing some registers like `ebp->rbp`. Would you please give me some suggestions ?